# Invalid preceding regular expression given by sed

Tags: regex, bash, command-line, sed

I am  and have been working on a sed script file and I am running into an "Invalid Preceding regular expression" error when I run it. Below is the file in its entirety.

I have done much search on  this already, both on this site and else where. Many questions asked here have resulted in needing to be either extend regular expressions something being escaped incorrectly. I have defined this as a extended expresion already as it is needed for the email substitution.

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
#/find_this thing/{
#s/ search_for_this/ replace_with_this/
#s/ search_for_this_other_thing/ replace_with_this_other_thing/
#}

#Search and replace #ServerAdmin (with preceding no space) email addresses using a regular expression that has the .com .net and so on domain endings as option so it will find root@localhost and replace it in line with admin's email address.

ServerAdmin/ { 
s/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(\.[A-Za-z]]{2,4})?\b/email@example.com/
}
#Enable user's Public HTML directories
/UserDir/ {
s/disable$/enable/ 
s/^#User/User/
}
#Replace the only #ServerName (with preceding no space) followed space and text with Our server ip
/#ServerName */ c\ ServerName server.ip.address.here/
```

I am calling it from termal as ./config-apache.sed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and get this returned.

```
/bin/sed: file ./apache-install.sed line 12: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

inside of vim line 12 is i dentified as the single `}` above `#Enable user's Public HTML directories`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It appears the GNU `sed` does not like the PCRE non-capturing notation:

```
...(?:...)...
```

Try:

```
s/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(\.[A-Za-z]]{2,4})?\b/email@example.com/
```

GNU `sed` seems to be OK with that.  However, you still have a little work to do.  Given the first line below as input, the output is the second line:

```
abc def@ghi.jk aaa
abc email@example.comjk aaa
```

There are two problems giving that result:

1. The `]]` should be a single `]`.
2. You're looking for a trailing dot in the prior regex, so you don't want one in the last part of the domain suffix.

This does the job:

```
s/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([A-Za-z]{2,4})?\b/email@example.com/

abc def@ghi.jk aaa
abc email@example.com aaa
```

Comment: Much appreciated, I caught the ]] i had in there but kept over looking the the second dot. It drove me crazy last night.  I will give it a whirl and see if it give me what I was looking for.

Comment: This solution does in need work after removing the PCRE non-capturing notation and and making the search for the dot optional as well as I need to match a "@localhost" address. However when actually running the corrected script it shows that it replaces items when it dumps the conf to STDOUT but when re-parsing with `sed -rne '/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+([A-Za-z]{2,4})?\b/p' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` it shows that no changes have been made.

Comment: Did you mean to include a `-i (or `-i.bak`) option so it overwrites the original file?  (That's assuming you have GNU `sed`, of course.)  (For 'localhost' emails, I think you simply need a second regex; certainly, that will be easier than forcing it into the one you already have.)

Comment: I got it work with `sed -i -rf apache-install.sed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and kept the same regex just by making the dot detection optional with `(\.)?` 
Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Another hour-long headache circumvented. I love this site.

Comment: I still haven't specifically familiarized myself with the common regular expression engines, but heard `sed` implements up to 1 complex set of expressions with the `-r` option.  I keep forgetting it still falls short of a full PCRE implementation that adds `(?:...)` non-capturing groups, look-arounds like `(?!...)`, and even short-hand character classes such as `\d` for digits, and probably more...